# How to alternative male and female in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server: how to get the alternate data of male and female data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpGenders]
(
    [id] [INT] NULL,
    [Name] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Gender] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpGenders] ([id], [Name], [Gender]) 
VALUES (1, N'Manish', N'Male'), (2, N'Nayak', N'Male'),
       (3, N'Martin', N'Male'), (4, N'Roy', N'Male'),
       (5, N'Hardik', N'Male'), (6, N'Manisha', N'Female'),
       (7, N'Kruti', N'Female'), (8, N'Maria', N'Female')
```

Based on the above data, I want an output like this:

```
Id | Name    | Gender 
---+---------+---------
1  | Manish  | Male
6  | Manisha | Female
2  | Nayak   | Male
7  | Kruti   | Female
3  | Martin  | Male
8  | Maria   | Female
4  | Roy     | Male
5  | Hardik  | Male
```

I tried this SQL statement:

```
select 
    id, name, gender  
from 
    (select 
         *,
         row_number() over (order by id, gender) as rn
     from  
         [Test].[dbo].[EmpGenders]) a
where  
    rn % 2 = 1 

union all

select 
    id, name, gender  
from 
    (select 
         *, row_number() over (order by id desc, gender desc) as rn
     from  
         [Test].[dbo].[EmpGenders]) a  
where  
    rn % 2 = 0
```

but that query not returning the expected result.

Can you please tell me how to write a query to achieve this task in SQL Server?

Comment: what do you mean by alternate data ?

Answer (score 6):

Could you not just do...

```
SELECT *
FROM EmpGenders
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Gender ORDER BY Id),
         Gender DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 more column to each subquery, like `num = 0 or 1` for each gender:

```
select id, name, gender from (
  select * ,row_number()over ( order by id )as rn, 0 as num
  from  [EmpGenders]
  where gender = 'Male'
  union all
  select * ,ROW_NUMBER()over ( order by id )as rn, 1 as num
  from  [EmpGenders] 
  where gender = 'Female'
  ) t
order by t.rn, t.num
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b0eda4110172378986d345318eea38b)
*Note:*
Larnu's answer that was deleted(!!!) is better....